# Values changes when insert into database : MySQL : Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, insert

I am trying to enter a value **113762008372628** in the table, It changes into **1209603476** after insertion. I print the value just before saving it and it is showing fine but as soon as it enters the table, It changes.

I have tried the following solutions,

- Change the table
- Change the ColumnName
- Change Column type to **varchar** with limit 1000
- Change Column type to **Bigint**
- Change Column type to **Text**

Still no luck.

I am using Laravel 5.6 and use Eloquent method to save the values.

The inserted code:

```php
foreach ($ordersArray as $o) { 
    $orders = new \App\Orders; 
    $orders->store_id = '6'; 
    $orders->OrderId = $o->OrderId; 
    $orders->save(); 
}
```

***Any help would be highly appreciated.***

Comment: can us post the `insert` code and your field type, because bigint is enough to `113762008372628 `

Comment: Well, unless you have a trigger on that table, you've eliminated MySQL as the cause of this problem.

Comment: What happens if you change the first number up or down by one? Does it affect the result?

Comment: MySQL have no problems to store such values. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6382d288abec0b6e25e02fffec74e4d1). Check does you REALLY send this value to MySQL (maybe laravel truncates? 113762008372628 MOD 2^32 = 1209603476).

Comment: @TsaiKoga insert code,

foreach ($ordersArray as $o) {

 $orders = new \App\Orders;

 $orders->store_id = '6';

 $orders->OrderId = $o->OrderId;
 $orders->save();
}

Comment: @Jason if I change the first number, yes it affect the result also.

Comment: Why voting down ? what is unclear ? Kindly mention in the comments

Comment: which column' value is `113762008372628`. `$o->OrderId`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes....

Comment: @Arshi `$o` is from other Model? is  order's column `OrderId` unsigned?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I fetched the data from an API, stored it in `$ordersArray` and then apply loop on it,  So `$o` does not belong to any model, and `OrderId` is not unsigned.

Comment: plz desc this table, and post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206709/discussion-between-arshi-and-tsaikoga).